# Flutter: delete generated files

Tags: flutter

I cloned a git repo and it contains generated files. Is there a command to delete the generated files?

The project uses `moor_generator`, `pubspec_generator` and `json_serializable`.

What kind/format of files would I have to delete manually?

Comment: if you just want to delete the files and regenerate new ones running the build command with delete flags works `flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`

Comment: @griffins Yes, this is what i wanted, thanks. Could you write it as an answer so i can mark it correct one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you just want to delete the files and regenerate new ones running the build command with delete flags works `flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`